# page is displaying error page instead of intended page

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This code is really puzzling me as to why this is happening. if i add the [R=302,L]
then my link works perfectly as i would hope. but if i don't add it and i have just [L]
the it goes to an error page. Isn't the difference between R and no R just whether or not the address bar in the browser is updated?

This is for the **last line in the code**. I am trying to do an internal/silent mod_rewrite

I want whether the user types http://example.com or http://example.com/home/

I want the same url internally http://example.com/home

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working

RewriteBase /

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .css

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js
Options +Multiviews

RewriteEngine On

#NC not case sensitive
#L last rule don't process futher
#R 301 changes the url to what you want


#changes the host to make sure it has no www infront
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.host56\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.host56.com [R=302,L]


#kills request with file extensions
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(php|jsp|html|jsp|asp)/?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule .* - [F]

#selects home
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\ HTTP/1.1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ home/ [L]
```

Comment: So is there a /home/index.php or /home/index.html file that is actually handle the request?

Comment: it is a /home/index.php shouldn't really matter. it should automatically look for an index file

Answer (score 0):

By passing the `R=***` flag you are forcing the browser to actually make a new request against the server at the new URL. On the subsequent request, since the host name is already what you want, this will obviously skip this condition on the next request and continue with the rest of the htaccess logic.

If you remove this and leave only the `L` flag. You are indicating that this is the LAST rule in htaccess that you should process, so the following rules in the file will never get executed (which I guess results in an error page for you).

Comment: there are no more rules after it. I deleted the [L] but i still get the same error. I thought that the R only makes a difference in the browser and it updates but internally i should still be serving the same content

Comment: @Lpc_dark No. `R=***` cause an external browser redirect. It will make a second request against this server. You can't just change the URL in the browser without triggering a page reload as this would be a horrible security hole (anyone could phish their site as Google, Amazon, or whatever). What do you mean there are no rules after it?  There are two rules after you `[R=302,L]`, perhpas they are just not being triggered.

Comment: no i am talking about the last rule. I know that the first one works so does the second one and the third rule is what i am talking about. I know R which stands for redirect sends a 301 (permanent) or 302(temp) and i know the browser reload. I am saying for the last rule why does the R load the page while without the R it doesn't. It's all on the same domain

Comment: @Lpc_dark Because the `R` flag forces a reload.  The `R` flag makes an external redirect, changing the URL in the browser. You are changing the URL in the browser so there MUST be a reload.

Comment: K so with out the R flag it shouldn't redirect but the browser should still display the same thing? it's just that it won't show the redirect?

Comment: problem is with the R flag the page loads while without it i get an error. shouldn't it be still redirecting to the same thing? thanks for all your help by the way really appreciate it, :)

Comment: I should also not that it is very odd to use `THE_REQUEST` here if you don't actually care about `GET/POST` or `HTTP/1.1` values. I would suggest `REQUEST_URI`

Comment: I stopped using the REQUEST_URI because apache updates it after internal redirects so i didn't want if i added a rule earlier it does something weird

Comment: @Lpc_dark So why is it a problem that your page loads with R flag? You haven't really explained the logic of what you are trying to do here. It would appear to me that you are simply trying to redirect request with URI of `/` to `/home` When you use `R` the last rule will never trigger because the request is being sent as `/home` after the redirect.